# redirect after apply button joomla

Tags: php, forms, redirect, joomla

I have a simple query

```
     <button type="button" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('propform.apply')">
            <?php echo JText::_('JAPPLY') ?>
```

I want to redirect this to a new tab after the apply function - is there any easy way to achieve this: (some kind of onclick - redirect function after the apply function)?
Thanks in advance
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a controller that extends JControllerForm, then you could achieve this by overriding the save function.

```php
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null)
{
    parent::save($key, $urlVar);

    $task = $this->getTask();
    if($task == 'apply') {
        $this->setRedirect(
            JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=anothertab', false)
        );
    }
}
```